# How do i get the response from a Firebase function to client in ionic

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to understand how the promise works in terms of response to client side from a firebase function, i will give here a very simple example:

This is the ionic method saving some data which then triggers a function in firebase:

```
helloworld() {
   this.db.list(`/helloWorld/${this.userId}`).push({status: false})
     .then(res => console.log(res))
}
```

Firebase function triggered

```
exports.helloWorld = database
 .ref('helloworld/{id}')
 .onWrite((change, context) => {
   const data = change.after.val();
   const id = context.params.id;

return admin
  .database()
  .ref(`/helloWorld/${id}`)
  .set({ status: true }).then((res) => res);
```

});

[image: Here is the log from the helloworld method on client side, it seems is a database reference:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All background type functions, including Realtime Database triggers, don't "return" anything to the client that made the change.  The only thing the client knows is that it made a change.

The promise returned by background functions serves only one purpose - to tell Cloud Functions when all the async work from that function is complete.  They don't communicate anything back to the client.

If you need a background function to deliver some information back to the client, you'll need some sort of communication channel for that.  The function could write back into the database at a location agreed upon with the client, or it could use Firebase Cloud Messaging to ping the app.  There is no one right way to do this - you're going to have to come up with something that suits your needs.